# How can I use javascript to make a working image slider work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm trying to make an image slider for my website but I can't get the buttons (left and right) to move the images

This is what I want to go for: https://jsfiddle.net/Narek_T/wsemLhtz/6/

```
$(".arrow-click").click(function() {
  var box = $(".image-container"),
    x;
  if ($(this).hasClass("arrow-right")) {
    x = ((box.width() / 2)) + box.scrollLeft();
    box.animate({
      scrollLeft: x,
    })
  } else {
    x = ((box.width() / 2)) - box.scrollLeft();
    box.animate({
      scrollLeft: -x,
    })
  }
})
```

This is what I have so far:
https://jsfiddle.net/7qfpa245/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
                <div class="image-container-outer">
                  <div class="left-scroll arrow-click arrow-left">&#8672;</div>
                  <div class="right-scroll arrow-click arrow-right">&#8674;</div>

                <div class="image-container">
                  <img src="https://images.ecosia.org/42-uZar58L8RQsWtZWq_TtJXV1A=/0x390/smart/http%3A%2F%2Fwallpapers-image.ru%2F1920x1080%2Fsummer%2Fwallpapers%2Fsummer-wallpapers-1920x1080-0001.jpg" alt="DW Image" class="port-image" />
                  <img src="https://images.ecosia.org/42-uZar58L8RQsWtZWq_TtJXV1A=/0x390/smart/http%3A%2F%2Fwallpapers-image.ru%2F1920x1080%2Fsummer%2Fwallpapers%2Fsummer-wallpapers-1920x1080-0001.jpg" alt="DW Image" class="port-image" />
                  <img src="https://images.ecosia.org/42-uZar58L8RQsWtZWq_TtJXV1A=/0x390/smart/http%3A%2F%2Fwallpapers-image.ru%2F1920x1080%2Fsummer%2Fwallpapers%2Fsummer-wallpapers-1920x1080-0001.jpg" alt="DW Image" class="port-image" />
                </div>
              </div>
```

So the problem was in your HTML. You were detecting the click event on the 'arrow-click' class but then checking for an 'arrow-right' class that didn't exist in your javascript.

Adding that class to the HTML has you scrolling.

edit: here is a fiddle of the working result https://jsfiddle.net/k3jsx17f/

edit2: here is another JSFiddle of a vanilla JS version (no libraries like jQuery) which might help if you can't get jQuery working (worth working on getting jQuery working though, if you ask me) https://jsfiddle.net/k3jsx17f/1/

edit3: So the main issue you were having was understanding how to attach events to HTML nodes or jQuery objects. In order to attach events to jQuery objects you need to make sure the DOM has rendered so that you have something to attach to. This is why you need to put your event listeners *within* your document.ready function. Doing this will make it so your code, where you are attaching your arrow-click element to the click event, waits until it is loaded and ready in the DOM before executing. It's a small fix, but understanding the why will definitely assist your web-development in the future.

Comment: Thank you very much but I still can't seem to get it to work. There must be another issue somewhere else :(

Comment: Hi Jonathan, I've edited my answer to link a JSFiddle so that you can see that it's working. Let me know if you still need help. (also, I just noticed that I had the arrow's classes backwards and I've updated the answer to reflect that, my apologies ((it still should have worked though)))

Comment: This is really frustrating me! All the code is now correct and I now know that I've got an issue with linking jQuery or one of the files. I'm very new to javascript and jQuery and I'm trying to get to grips with it. I'm a bit confused because some of my javascript works in the "javascript.js" file, but this slider doesn't seem to link correctly or something.

Edit: Here is my <head> section: https://jsfiddle.net/frck7jnv/

Comment: It sounds like you are having an issue with importing jQuery. I checked your reference and it works fine though. Are you writing this code solely in a JSFiddle or are you using a desktop IDE?

Comment: I'm using Atom editor on my PC. This is what my javascript.js looks like: (https://jsfiddle.net/r7x148qy/). I've been trying to figure out what's wrong for so long now. I bet it's something simple in the end. You've been very helpful thank you very much :) It's just odd that some of the code works in the javascript.js and some doesn't even though it works in jsfiddle

Comment: If you open this in Chrome and hit F12 do you have any errors  listed in the console area?

Comment: None at all. Even when I click the left and right buttons. I've also cleared all my cookies

Comment: So this is everything put together and working in JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/45rjx6p8/. But you're saying that some of it is not working when you try to run it in Atom. What is not working? Are you sure your reference to your javascript.js file is accurate? Can you get that file to do anything at all, like if you add a simple alert('working') call to the top of javascript.js, right after the document.ready function does it alert when you load?

Comment: It doesn't make sense because some of the scripts I have in my javascript.js work and are functional on the website, however, others don't work like the scroller bit. Does it require me to link a different framework for that specific script or what? The only thing that is different between the two jsfiddles that I made was changing it from plain javascript to javascript with jQuery

Comment: Ok I just experimented a bit more and I changed the framework from jQuery to some other one then switched it back then run it again and the slider didn't work! Even though it was using jQuery which worked before. I think it may be a browser issue? Bad code? Not sure

Comment: I'm a little confused by your responses. It's hard to tell what the issue is unless we take it one thing at a time. I doubt it's a browser issue, but we'll get to the bottom of it. I think the thing to eliminate first is whether your HTML file is communicating with your JS file. Comment everything out except for something very basic like a console.log('working') or something like that. See if that's working and then maybe try $(function) {console.log('working')}. Are you using source control like git? If so, if you give me a link to your repo I'll clone it and see what I can find for you.

Comment: I added in an alert to the javascript file and it worked when I refreshed my page. I've pushed it all to a git repository for you so you can take a look at everything. Thank you very much for all this help! - https://github.com/JonathanLangton1/jonathan-langton

There is one error in console that only occured when I uploaded it to github (github page link: (https://jonathanlangton1.github.io/jonathan-langton/)

Comment: Alright Jon, I've got you sorted out. So you were having a couple of issues, both relatively minor. First, you only need one $(document).ready function just move the fade-in piece inside the other document.ready and delete the other ready function. Then the other, and more important piece I'll edit my answer above to explain.

Comment: Thank you very much! This has fixed everything! My javascript knowledge is quite slim at the moment but I'm eager to learn more :) Thank you very much for all your help! I've updated my git page :P